# Can we convert "mac" fonts to "pc" fonts with Linux command line or a PHP script?

Tags: php, linux, fonts

Can we convert "mac" fonts to "pc" fonts with the Linux command line or a PHP script?

Or any other LAMP-centric way? Or ImageMagick?

How do the font files differ for mac versus pc anyway? A font is a font is a font surely?

Ideas or advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: The OpenType format (all adobe fonts are now OTF) is cross-platform and requires no file conversion AFAIK. (See: http://www.adobe.com/type/opentype/ ). As far as I know, PHP's GD Truetype routine imagettftext also supports OTF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) for format conversions too. Not sure if there are any commandline tools.

Edit. Ok, there is: http://fondu.sourceforge.net/ and some tools in the `t1utils` package.

Comment: Very useful, practical answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A font is like a word processor document — they can be expressed in lots of different ways.

There is no such thing as "A Mac word processor document" and a "A Windows word processor document". There are "Word documents", "OpenOffice documents", "Pages documents" and so on.

How you convert between different types of font file depends on the type of font file.

The vast majority of fonts (on Windows, Mac and *nix) use the TrueType format these days.

Comment: It would be different for them to work on Windows, Mac and *nix if they weren't OS-independent.